# Degree sequence multigraph without loop

Tags: graph-theory, multigraphs

I am trying to prove the following

> $d_n$ is a degree-sequence of the multigraph  $G$ (without loops) if and only if $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{d_i}$ is even and $d_1 \le\sum_{i=2}^{n}{d_i}$

I have no problems showing the first part.

By the "handshake"-lemma $\sum_{i=1}^{n}{d_i}=2e$ where $e$ is the number of edges in $G$

$$d_1 \le e $$

$$d_1\le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}{d_i}}{2}$$

Hence $d_1 \le \sum_{i=2}^{n}{d_i}$

However, I don't know how to show the other part. Would appreciate some tips or hints

Comment: I would try induction on the number of edges $e$. For the inductive step, suppose all sequences $(d_1, d_2, \cdots d_n)$ which sums up to $2e$ have a graph, For $(d_1, d_2, \dots, d_m)$ summing up to $2(e+1)$, try to add an edge from a graph of degree $(d_1-1, d_2-1, d_3, \cdots, d_m)$.

Comment: @HwChu Gonna try that and report back :P Thx for ur quick response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let's consider non-decreasing sequence of integer not negative numbers and $d_1 \geq d_2 \geq \cdots \geq d_n \geq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905496/lets-consider-non-decreasing-sequence-of-integer-not-negative-numbers-and-d-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the construction I've found. As far as I know, the result was first proven by Hakimi in 1962 (check the article [On Realizability of a Set of Integers as Degrees of the Vertices of a Linear Graph](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/83b1/608fb33eef2467a53f6ccffed559df7408dc.pdf)).

**Theorem.** Let $d_1\leq...\leq d_n$ be a sequence of natural numbers. This sequence can be realized by some multigraph iff $S=d_1+...+d_n$ is even and $d_n\leq S/2$.

**Proof**. The necessary part follows from the handshaking lemma. Let's prove that the conditions are also sufficient.

If $n=1$, the only possibility is $d_1=0$. This case is trivially realizable, thus suppose $n\geq2$. Consider $n$ vertices $v_1,...,v_n$. Connect $v_1$ and $v_2$ with $d_1$ edges, $v_2$ and $v_3$ with $d_2-d_1$ edges, $v_3$ and $v_4$ with $d_1-(d_2-d_1)$ edges, etc. You'll get a graph $G$ of the following form (with the degrees subscribed):

[image]

$G$ is almost corresponding to our sequence: we have to add $d_n-x$ new edges to $v_n$ to complete the construction. This addition is possible if $G'=G-v_n$ contains enough edges, then you may cut some edge from $G'$ in two parts connecting these parts with $v_n$. The procedure will obviously preserve the degrees of $v_1,...,v_{n-1}$ and will increase $d(v_n)$ by $2$:

[image]

Now, we have to prove that $G'$ contains at least $(d_n-x)/2$ edges (it's easy to see that $d_n-x$ is even). If this is not the case, then $|E(G')|=(d_1+...+d_{n-1}-x)/2<(d_n-x)/2$. This implies $d_1+...+d_{n-1}<d_n$ and $S/2<d_n$ giving us a contradiction $\blacksquare$

Let's show how the described method works applied to $2,4,6,8$:

[image]

Comment: This would be better typed out, and without sentences such as "The essential part is obvious." (Why is it obvious? And if it's that essential, why are you skipping it?)

Comment: @Misha I mean the necessary condition

Comment: I would suggest a minor edit to correct your English, but...

Comment: @Misha I've changed it

Comment: Thank you! I realize that typing it out is a lot of work just based on the random criticism of someone on the internet, but I think you have a nice argument now that will help many people if they find it.

Comment: @Misha actually, it was useful since helped to fix some little mistakes