# Let's consider non-decreasing sequence of integer not negative numbers and $d_1 \geq d_2 \geq \cdots \geq d_n \geq 0$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that such sequence is a graph sequence  of some graph $G$ which does not contain loops iff $d_1 \leq d_2 + d_3 + \cdots + d_n$.

IMPORTANT: by condition $d_1 + d_2 + \cdots + d_n = 2k$ for some integer $k$

I was trying to solve this one by assuming that $d_1 > d_2 + d_3 + \cdots + d_n$. I was planning on coming to contradiction. But I haven't managed to.

All ideas for solution will be much appreciated!

Comment: This is false; for example, there is no graph with degree sequence $1, 1, 1, 1, 1$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov of course we consider numbers with even sum, otherwise it doesn’t make any sense. I will edit the question

Comment: What about the sequence $2,2$? There's only one edge to place out of each vertex. You seem to be talking about multigraphs, not graphs.

Comment: Yes - it would be clearer if you specified that you were working with multigraphs, not simple graphs.  Also, in the title you should say "non-increasing" not "non-decreasing".

Answer (score 2):

For the forward (only if) direction, , let $G$ be a graph that does not contain any loops and has degree sequence $d_1,d_2,\ldots,d_n$. Any edge incident on the vertex of degree $d_1$ must also be incident on one of the vertices of degree $d_2,\ldots,d_n$. That is, the number of edges incident on this vertex is upper-bounded by the sum of the remaining degrees, which is exactly what we want.

For the backward (if) direction, consider the sequence $d_1-d_n,d_2,\ldots,d_{n-1}$. If $d_1-d_n$ is the largest element in this sequence, then we clearly have $$d_1-d_n\leq d_2+\cdots+d_{n-1}.$$
On the other hand, if $d_2$ is the largest element, then because $d_1\geq d_2$ and $d_{n-1}\geq d_n$, we have $$(d_1-d_n)+d_3+\cdots+d_{n-1}\geq d_2 + (d_{n-1}-d_n)\geq d_2.$$

Try using induction to complete the argument from here: construct a graph with this degree sequence, add a new vertex $v_n$, and add $d_n$ edges from the vertex with degree $d_1-d_n$ to $v_n$.

Comment: This is a nice enjoyable proof (+1).  To avoid confusion, it is worth pointing out that the reduction cannot proceed in three cases, but each of these has an "easy" solution (e.g. multigraph with required degrees): (i) the degrees are all equal and even, (ii) the degrees are all equal and $n$ is even, (iii) $n=3$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove the "only if" direction, note that each edge coming out of the vertex of degree $d_1$, also has an endpoint which is one of
the vertices of degree $d_2,d_3,\cdots,d_n$.